# wso2 identity server write correct user attributes to openldap

Tags: addition, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I wonder if anyone can help. I am working on a project that requires the use of wso2is and openldap together on linux. I am quite new to both technologies, so there may be some things I dont quite understand properly.

I have set openldap up as a secondary user store in wso2is. In openldap, using ldif files I have managed to create groups, and some dummy users. These entries can be read and displayed successfully by wso2is. The good user entries follow the format below

[image]

In wso2is I can create new users for the secondary data store and it lookks like I can assign them to the different roles. The problem is that when I create a new user in wso2, it seems to be lacking certain attributes such as password, and mail. When I view users created in wso2 (using ldap admin) they are different to users created manually using ldif. I dont know how to add the extra attributes such as email to new users created using wso2 (The extra attributes are necessary for ldap to log into another program).

The image below for user "bob" does not have the correct attributes. 
[image]

The other things I dont understand is that in wso2is if I set 'cn' as the username attribute and try to view the extra attribute fields for users I created in wso2, I get an 'error reading metadata screen'. However if I set 'uid' as the username attribute and try to view extra attributes, I am allowed to see them (most are blank), but if I try to populate those fields such as surname or mail, I then get an error message saying they are not supported by the underlying ldap.

Maybe Im missing something fundamental but I dont know what it is, apparently it almost does what I want.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure an external LDAP, you need to map its attributes to the WSO2 local Claims. Because with in WSO2 Identity Server all user attributes are considered as claims. Hence please try mapping secondary userstore attributes to the each local claim in the user profile. For example http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress claim can be mapped your secondary user-store attribute as shown in the image. 
[image]

Moreover, Hope you have added User Search Base, User Search Filter and User List filter properly in the secondary userstore configurations.